# How to use `VueI18n` with typescript and `vue2.0`? `new VueI18n({..})` report `has no construct signatures` error

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I followed the [installation guide](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/installation.html#yarn) but getting error at `Vue.use(VueI18n);` and `const i18n = new VueI18n({...});`.

`Vue.use(VueI18n)` reports

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(plugin: PluginObject<unknown> | PluginFunction<unknown>, options?: unknown): VueConstructor<Vue>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<unknown> | PluginFunction<unknown>'.
      Property 'install' is missing in type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n")' but required in type 'PluginObject<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(plugin: PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>, ...options: any[]): VueConstructor<Vue>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<any> | PluginFunction<any>'.
      Property 'install' is missing in type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n")' but required in type 'PluginObject<any>'.
    12 | import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
    13 | 
  > 14 | Vue.use(VueI18n);
```

and
`const i18n = new VueI18n({...});` reports

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n")' has no construct signatures.
```

Here is my `Vue` instance.

```
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 2):

it seams you are using Vue version 2
try to install a compatible version of VueI18n by type the following command:

npm install vue-i18n@8 --save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).